# Inherit itself using partial specialization

Tags: c++, inheritance, partial-specialization

I have a `class A` which defines a lot of functions and I want to create a *partial specialization* of `A` which defines some more functions. I've read about a `class` inheriting itself but only with full specialization. So

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    void foo() {...}
    void bar() {...}
};

template<typename T>
struct A<T*> : A<T*> // a class cannot be its own base class, here I want to inherit A without partial specialization
{
   void baz() {...}
};
```

Comment: This cannot be done in C++ as is. Although there are several workaround they all have one or other kind of problems. You need to redesign your class hierarchy to avoid this issue completely.

Comment: Create another template and move A's members to it. Then inherit both the primary template A and the specializations from it.